# How stop refreshing the kendo grid while selecting dropdown inside grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-grid

Acutally i am using kendo tree view. If i click check box it will create another one grid inside of Activity Column.In that one of the column is outputcategorycode. when ever i am clicking the none value one dropdown will bind dynamically there. then i need to select any one of the value in that dropdown. Once selection is done , checkbox is changing to uncheck mode then inside grid also disappearing that means whole grid is refreshing.

Please have look my Dojo link and give me solution for that.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@bagya/iMeRi

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the `databinding` event and stop grid from refreshing. Adding this in `databound` will prevent grid from refreshing.

```
 $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").bind("dataBinding", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

Once you are done with 'doing stuff' you can unbind the function by simply calling

```
grid.unbind("dataBinding");
```

[Check your updated dojo with the changes](http://dojo.telerik.com/aWOTU) :

> NOTE : I have added it in databound of the grid just to show working,
>   but you probably should not do that, since it wont bind other grid data. So
>   add a different handler and based on *certain event* as per your
>   requirement, disable grid refresh and enabled after event is done.

**Update:**

You can use the `onOpen` and `onClose` event of the `kendoDropDownList`. Refer below:

**Bind the onOpen and onClose events to the dropdown**

```
 function OutputProductEditor(container, options) {  


        $('<input required data-text-field="Value" data-value-field="Key" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                //autoBind: false,
                dataSource: ProductData,
          close: onClose,
          open: onOpen,
            });
    }
```

**onOpen prevent refresh by adding databinding function**

```
function onOpen() {
                var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

   grid.bind("dataBinding", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
                };
```

**onClose - remove databinding**

```
  function onClose() {
                   var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                  grid.unbind("dataBinding");
                };
```

Here is the [updated dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/aWOTU/2)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It's working but i am not i need to add  "  grid.unbind("dataBinding");". Please help me

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Sorry for that comment mistake. Actually where i need to use this grid.unbind("dataBinding");". And how I need to use in my case. Thanks...

Comment: Further if any kendo related doubt I will ask you. How I can contact you?

Comment: Please reply how can I contact you?

Comment: Sorry. You can just ask here in comment, i'll try to help

Comment: Okay if I want to comment directly to you how can I do?

Comment: Comment on this post and i'll get a notification.

Comment: Sure Thanks :) May I know your name and from?

Comment: Hi, I want to have two way binding in kendo Grid. Whenever adding new value in grid it's  should add sourceData also but it's not adding , same thing i want to have for delete and update.. please check dojo link http://dojo.telerik.com/aTIba/7

Comment: Can you please give soultions for this question ..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071727/angularjs-with-kendo-grid-inline-mode-cancel-deletes-the-existing-records