# AngularJs with kendo grid inline mode cancel deletes the existing records?

Tags: angularjs, dojo, kendo-grid

I have grid and i am trying to add record it's adding and updating also. but while click edit and not changing any values and clicking cancel it's deleting existing row value from model. Please help me to resolve this issue.

I added dojo link here . http://dojo.telerik.com/enErE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` in schema should be an actual field.

```
    "schema": {
                  "model": {
                    "id": "cuobjid",
}
```

Also, if `id` is null i.e `cuobjid` is null then it will remove the row.

[Check updated dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/enErE/3)

Comment: Yeah..Mine is dynamically we are creating the grid. tha's why i am not able give exact id.  Any how i will make it happen, Thanks Dude..

Comment: I have another one issue. I am binding function for example" edit: grid_edit" , It's working in dojo. It's not working our real time. what will be the reason. pleae advice on this. FYI http://dojo.telerik.com/enErE/4

Comment: Sorry, I cant be sure why its not working in your environment, may be something is conflicting. try putting breakpoints in browser and see

Comment: Actually i tried but it's not calling the function.

Comment: I am facing another one issue. Actually i want to make two way binding in in kend grid. I am binding the datasource as a object. It;s not updating the value. please check my dojo.. http://dojo.telerik.com/EzuVA

Comment: Actually the datasource which assigned on that. it's angular scope.model          scope.mainGridOptions[scope.gridId].dataSource = scope.model[objectName].rowset;

Comment: Can you please help me on this question ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37388273/kendo-grid-default-methods-is-not-firing-in-angularjs